# Unable to SSH into GCP vm - troubleshoot showing no issue

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am unable to ssh into a gcp vm. When i try troubleshooting- it is not showing any issue.
[image]
I was able to ssh into other VMs.
FYI i have a Github instance installed into that vm.
this is the firewall config, i tried allowing both http and https- but it did not work.-

[image: firewall]

How do i proceed to troubleshoot further?

From GCP doc
*After an SSH connection fails, you have the option to Retry the connection, or Troubleshoot the connection using the SSH-in-browser troubleshooting tool.*
i did troubleshoot but all steps were green.

Comment: From the Compute Engine VM serial logs you can check also for a UFW block error warning then if you have seen this error follow this steps for troubleshooting:
1. Go to VM instances page > Click the name of your VM instance
2. Click the EDIT button at the top of the page
3. Scroll down to "Custom metadata" section
4. For the box Key, please input "startup-script"
5. On the Value box, input "sudo ufw allow 22"
6. Save your changes.
7. Once saved, please click on the RESET button at the top of the page.

Comment: Check whether or not the VM boot disk is full see this documentation on [Inaccessible VM due to full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize#inaccessible-vm) for general [Troubleshooting SSH errors](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#ssh_troubleshooting_tool) see this documentation.

Comment: Use the serial console to connect to the server. Then review the SSH server log file. The SSH server will log the reason for the authentication failure. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

As @John Hanley suggested on [troubleshooting using the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console) to check and view the error messages for authentication failure.

In addition to that from the Compute Engine VM serial logs you can check also for a UFW block error warning then if you have seen this error message follow this steps for troubleshooting:

1. Go to VM instances page > Click the name of your VM instance
2. Click the EDIT button at the top of the page
3. Scroll down to "Custom metadata" section
4. For the box Key, please input "startup-script"
5. On the Value box, input "sudo ufw allow 22"
6. Save your changes.
7. Once saved, please click on the RESET button at the top of the page.

Check also whether or not the VM boot disk is full see this documentation on [Inaccessible VM due to full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize#inaccessible-vm) for general [Troubleshooting SSH errors](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#ssh_troubleshooting_tool) see this documentation.